# How do I reset my password in IBM Cloud Node-red?

Tags: ibm-cloud, node-red, change-password

I can sign on to IBM cloud and used to click on "Visit App URL" and Node red would start.  Now it is asking for username and password. I think I remember the username but not my password.  How do I request a password reset?

Answer (score 0):

You don't request a reset, the credentials you created when you set up the Node-RED instance can be over ridden by setting the following environment variables in the IBM Cloud console:

```
NODE_RED_USERNAME
NODE_RED_PASSWORD
```

More details can be found here: https://nodered.org/docs/platforms/bluemix